# Passing ghc-options to Stack script interpreter

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using Stack interpreter feature and having a code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack 
-- stack script --resolver lts-12.7 --package yesod 

main = print "hello"
```

I want to pass the `ghc-options` option to the stack interpreter to it. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent version of Stack supports `ghc-options` directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack 
-- stack script --resolver lts-12.7 --package yesod --ghc-options -Wall

main = print "hello"
```

And on executing:

```
$ stack jest.hs

/home/sibi/github/subsite/jest.hs:4:1: warning: [-Wmissing-signatures]
    Top-level binding with no type signature: main :: IO ()
  |
4 | main = print "hello"
  | ^^^^
"hello"
```